# как создать двухколоночный шаблон страницы wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

как создать двухколоночный шаблон страницы wordpress?

Comment: Изучить верстку

Comment: @SeVlad верстку основы я знаю. но саму логику не могу понять, как сделать подобный шаблон. создать отдельный файл шаблона, к примеру two-col.php вставить 2 колонки bootstrap и в них прописать the_content() ? вопрос в том как сделать, чтобы в самом шаблоне можно было выбирать в какую колонку вставлять контент. Ответ может быть и не слишком подробный, а просто какие функции для этого нужны

Comment: Колонки - это чистая верстка. Функции ВП - это ЧТО выводить.

Comment: Можете использовать какой-нибудь визуальный редактор, типа Visual Composer. Или кастомные поля в плагине Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: Согласен с @KAGGDesign с помощью ACF - это оооочень быстро делается. А для выбора куда выводить влево или вправо, просто можно добавить чекбокс, и в файле шаблона уже с помощью условия этого выводить содержимое мета-полей.